# SD card mounting trouble

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card

Im trying to mount an SD card, And it generally (~80%) works great for a few seconds, Long enough for me to see the folder structure, and then unmounts itself.

I need to have it monuted long enough to remove the data from the card. Output from dmesg

```
[ 1564.205285] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 16600
[ 1564.207403] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[ 1564.207415] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[ 1564.207422] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1564.207434] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[ 1564.207438] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1564.207445] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[ 1564.207451] Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1564.207457] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[ 1564.207460] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 41 c8 00 00 10 00
[ 1564.207478] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 16840
[ 1564.209517] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[ 1564.209529] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[ 1564.209537] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1564.209546] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[ 1564.209555] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1564.209567] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[ 1564.209577] Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1564.209586] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[ 1564.209591] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 3f d8 00 00 08 00
[ 1564.209618] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 16344
[ 1564.223579] sdb: detected capacity change from 3980394496 to 0
```

Ive tried running fsck.vfat but it doesn't stay mounted long enough to properly start.

Card is currently in read only mode, and trying to remove the data with dd, But the same problem occurs, Its data disappears long before i can get anything meaningful

What are my best options to remove the data from this drive ?

Comment: Remove, or retrieve? Your question's wording is a little vague as to your intentions

Comment: Either, im not bothered if the SD card is not used again as long as the data comes back

Comment: Have you tried a different card reader ?

Comment: some error with kingston microSD card

Answer (score 0):

Use GNU DDRescue to make a copy of the disk (you can restart it and continue where you left off, among other tricks) - then read the data off the copy of the disk.